# How to do a loop over a list and use a 'when' condition

Tags: ansible

I have a list of packages, saved as a variable:
pkg_list:
  - dstat
  - iftop
  - innotop
  - MySQL-python
  - mytop
  - winrar

I'm having a hard time trying to create a task to:
1) check if is installed (using yum module with 'list' command)
2) create a when condition over a loop to run a task when package isn't available

I'm trying to understand how a condition loop work over each value/item on a list.

```
pkg_list:
  - dstat
  - iftop
  - innotop
  - MySQL-python
  - mytop
  - winrar

- name: "Check if package is installed - Oracle"
  yum:
    list: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ pkg_list }}"
  register: pkg_stats
- debug: msg={{ pkg_stats }}
```

I guess the result is supposed to be:

- check every item if is present
- for item 1, when not present do this...
- for item 2, when not present do this...
- and so it goes...

Answer (score 0):

So not knowing how your repository is setup, you may have additional complications over this, but this debug task will one, skip the debug if the package doesn't exist in your repo, and then 2, only show information if the package is installed.

```
- debug: var=item.results|selectattr('yumstate','equalto','installed')|list
  with_items: "{{ pkg_stats.results }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{item.item }}"
  when: item.results | length > 0
```

I also threw in the loop control stuff, because that item iterator in your output is going to be really ugly and not very helpful if you don't pair it down, but its not required for what you are trying to do.

So if you have multiple repositories, or multiple versions of the same package in your repository, and without knowing what you are doing next, this task might not show all of the permutations of filters and whens, but this should get you closer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `package_facts` module to get information about which packages are installed. The result will be stored in the `ansible_facts.packages` variable.

```
- name: Gather package facts
  package_facts:
    manager: rpm

- name: Show package facts
  debug:
    var: ansible_facts.packages
```

You can then have tasks that are conditional on whether or not the packages are installed. For example, the following task will print out debug info for only the packages in your list which are not installed:

```
- name: Print debug info for missing packages
  debug:
    var: item
  with_items: '{{ pkg_list }}'
  when: item not in ansible_facts.packages
```